# Jenkins Pipeline Choice Input with List of Map in groovy not working

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following input in one of my Jenkins Pipeline Scripts:

```
def IMAGE_TAG = input message: 'Please select a Version', ok: 'Next',
    parameters: [choice(name: 'IMAGE_TAG', choices: imageTags, description: 'Available Versions')]
```

`imageTags` is a List of map e.g. :

```
imageTags : [
            [targetSuffix: "", sourceSuffix: "v2.17.1"],
]
```

When I run the script, I can select only `[targetSuffix: "", sourceSuffix: "v2.17.1"]` from the dropdown choice as expected.

In my script I can also see the value that gets selected:

```
echo "Selected Version = ${env.SELECTED_IMAGE_TAG}"

[Pipeline] echo Selected Version = {targetSuffix=, sourceSuffix=v2.17.1}
```

Now I wanted to find out which item from the original imageTags List got selected, but my script does not work as expected:

```
def selectedImageTag = imageTags.find { it.targetSuffix == "${env.SELECTED_IMAGE_TAG.targetSuffix}" }
```

I end up with the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: targetSuffix for class: java.lang.String
```

**My question is: How do I get the selected item of my choice out of the original List of maps?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input` step returns a string, so you can't write `env.SELECTED_IMAGE_TAG.targetSuffix`. You have to extract the substring, e. g. using a regular expression like this:

```
def match = ( env.SELECTED_IMAGE_TAG =~ /\{targetSuffix=(.*?), sourceSuffix=(.*?)\}/ )
if( match ) {
    def selectedTargetSuffix = match[0][1]
    def selectedImageTag = imageTags.find { it.targetSuffix == selectedTargetSuffix }
}
```

Comment: How would the match look like, if I wanted to compare on `sourceSuffix` instead?

Comment: OK I found it myself: Use `match[0][2]` instead for second capturing group.